# How to implement copy to clipboard in firefox without flash. Need implementaion

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How to implement copy to clipboard in Firefox without flash. Need implementation in java script asp.net-mvc.

Comment: This site is for advice, not your personal code factory.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access clipboard from JavaScript all (I hope) browsers block this.